# Why does threadpool hang with lots of tasks?

Tags: c++, threadpool

I have a simple threadpool:

added as suggested in comments:
https://godbolt.org/z/enrsc9h44

Also, I'm using MS VS 2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <string>

namespace threadpool
{
    class NotificationQueue
    {
        using lock_t = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;

        std::deque<std::function<void()>> queue;
        std::mutex lock;
        std::condition_variable signal;
        bool run{ true };

    public:
        void done()
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock{ lock };
            run = false;
        }

        bool pop(std::function<void()>& function)
        {
            
                lock_t _lock{ lock };

                while (queue.empty() && run)
                    signal.wait(_lock);

                if (queue.empty() | !run) return false;

                function = std::move(queue.front());
                queue.pop_front();
            
            return true;
        }

        template<typename Function>
        bool push(Function&& function)
        {
            {
                lock_t _lock{ lock, std::try_to_lock };

                if (!_lock)
                    return false;

                queue.emplace_back(std::forward<Function>(function));
            }
            signal.notify_one();
            return true;
        }

        bool try_pop(std::function<void()>& function)
        {
            {
                lock_t _lock{ lock, std::try_to_lock };

                if (!_lock || queue.empty()) return false;

                function = std::move(queue.front());
                queue.pop_front();
            }
            return true;
        }

        template<typename Function>
        bool try_push(Function&& function)
        {
            {
                lock_t _lock{ lock, std::try_to_lock };

                if (!_lock)
                    return false;

                queue.emplace_back(std::forward<Function>(function));
            }
            signal.notify_one();
            return true;
        }
    };

    class TaskSystem
    {
        const unsigned int count{ std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1 };

        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        std::vector<threadpool::NotificationQueue> queues { count };
        std::atomic<std::uint32_t> index { 0 };

        void run(std::uint32_t i)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                std::function<void()> function;

                for (std::uint32_t n = 0; n != count; ++n)
                {
                    if (queues[(i + n) % count].try_pop(function))
                        break;
                }

                if (!function && !queues[i].pop(function)) break;
                function();
            }
        }

    public:

        TaskSystem()
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i != count; ++i)
            {
                threads.emplace_back([&, i] { run(i); });
            }
        }

        ~TaskSystem()
        {
            for (auto& queue : queues)
                queue.done();

            for (auto& thread : threads)
                thread.join();
        }

        template<typename Function>
        void async(Function&& function)
        {
            auto i = index++;
            for (std::uint32_t n = 0; n != count; ++n)
            {
                if (queues[(i + n) % count].try_push(std::forward<Function>(function))) return;
            }

            queues[i % count].push(std::forward<Function>(function));
        }
    };
}
```

and just rnd benchmark:

```
void benchmark()
{
    struct Test
    {
        int i = 10000;
        int ii = 100240;
        int iii = 234;
        int iiii = 3325;
        int iiiii = 25235;
        int a = 324;
        int aa = 2353463;
        int aaa = 2456346;
        int aaaa = 3465345;
        int aaaaa = 43634635;
    };
    struct TTest
    {
        Test t;
        Test tt;
        Test ttt;
        Test tttt;
        Test ttttt;
    };
    std::uint32_t n = 1;
    Test testt;
    TTest test;


    int k = 432535235;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        k = (k / 3) * 3;
    //std::cout << 1;
}

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    {
        threadpool::TaskSystem TS;

        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            TS.async(std::bind(::benchmark));


        int a = 0;
        a += 2353455;
        a = a / 3;

    }

    const auto stop = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const auto secs = std::chrono::duration<double>(stop - start);
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << std::to_string(secs.count());

}
```

My problem is the TS sometimes hangs on thread.join(). I can't say that it's absolutely random but I rarely observe hangs when a little of tasks are added in TS but, once I push something like 10000 tasks (like in main()), most of the time the TS hangs forever in thread.join() with all queues empty.I have a feeling that I'm missing something obvious but I already scratched my head for last day w no good result.

1. I've tried to change run terminating condition but with no luck.
2. Adding std::cout << 1 (commented in code above) in benchmark() function makes it always work with any number of elements in queue.

Comment: Make your example in https://godbolt.org/ would help others to tinker your example quickly. Try to create one and you may get an answer sooner.

Comment: Also have you used debugger to break and see which thread is stuck?

Comment: yes, usually it hangs on very first join but sometimes passes through and hangs on 3rd or 4th.

Comment: The debugger is 100% the best tool for investigating this. If it hangs while joining threads, then one or more threads is still running. Break into the debugger and examine the call stack for each thread. A couple of issues I see are: 1) `if (queue.empty() | !run)` uses bitwise OR instead of logical OR; 2) `TaskSystem::run()` accesses `NotificationQueue::run` without mutex protection -- in your godbolt example only, which for some reason differs from what you posted here.

Comment: 1. oh my gosh, this one is typo. Thanks for noting this.
2. ooops, sorry about that. I've copy-pasted code from my studio into godbolt and forgot that I already performed more tests. Fixed now, thank you!